# How to change language when application is opened?

Tags: java, android

Currently, I have created a Values ​​file with strings.xml temporarily called the default language. And strings.xml in Values-en for example.

I created an additional SettingsActivity so I can change the language.When I use Code like this and refresh the application, the language has been changed.

```
String languageToLoad = "en";
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);

Configuration configuration = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
configuration.setLocale(locale);
Context context = createConfigurationContext(configuration);
Resources resources = context.getResources();
```

At the same time I saved SharePreferences with value en. I also added Code to check that Language value. And run the same Code above to be able to change the language according to the settings but it is not possible.

Let me ask, in Splash you have to refresh the application again. Or is there a way to save the selected language settings?

Comment: You don't need to do this manually: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages